# Integrity error while updading a UserProfile Serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an update `Serializer` and return a message for `Exception` `IntegrityError`.

snippet of the particular lines of codes is below-

```
    instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=instance.username).exists():
        raise BaseException
```

How can i return a message which says `username already exists` without using `Try` and `Except`

update-
This is how i fixed this problem-

```
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=instance.username).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("username already exists")
```

Comment: have you tried to put raise BaseException("the message you want") ?

Comment: @jalazbe yes, I have tried and it is making no difference. It is returning same result as BaseException `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `User.objects.filter(username__iexact=instance.username).exists()`

This won't work because the instance is also `User` object so it will always return `True`, you need to exclude the current instance first.

Fixed query:

```py
User.objects.exclude(pk=instance.pk).filter(username__iexact=instance.username).exists()
```

---

I don't know why you don't want to use `try/catch` but anyway, here's what you could do while following good patterns:

1. Django's `User` model already has the `unique=True` constraint.
2. Model instances that violate the UNIQUE constraint already throw an `IntegrityError` on call to `save()`.
3. So, in your view you just need to catch for the `IntegrityError` and then raise `serializers.ValidationError`.

```py
from rest_framework imports serializers, viewsets
from rest_framework.exceptions ValidationError

class UserProfileUpdateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        """
        Overwriting the method
        """
        try:
            serializer.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValidationError(
                f"Username already taken. Please choose another one.",
            )
```